# powershell -Or operator not working

Tags: powershell

Can someone tell me why the -or does not work.  If I run the code the first output is administrator which returns true but when it gets to the kahuna account it still returns false not true.

```
(Get-LocalUser).Name | Out-File C:\localusers.txt

ForEach ($User in Get-Content C:\localusers.txt)
{
    If ($User -match "administrator" -or "kahuna")
    {
        Write-Host True
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host False
    }
}
```

I get

> True, False, False, False, False

Here are the accounts listed in order they appear

> administrator, DefaultAccount, Guest, Kahuna, PCUser

Comment: Do you really get `True, False, False, False, False`? I expect it would be `True, True, True, True, True`, because not empty string result in `$true`, when converted to `[bool]`. So, your logical expression equivalent to `($User -match "administrator") -or $true`, which should always return `$true`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
If ($User -match "administrator" -or $User -match "kahuna")
```

Your `-or` operator doesn't tie the values of the previous operator together. You need to specify a 2nd conditional operator after `-or` I believe.

Comment: Awesome thanks!  I could swear I used that before and it didn't work... well now it's working.

Answer (score 4):

Nick is right, vote up his answer. You can also use parens if that is easier to see:

```
 If (($User -match "administrator") -or ($User -match "kahuna"))
```

The parens are implied and PSH sees them there anyway. With or without the parens, `$User = "administrator"` would first resolve to:

```
If (($true) -or ($false))
```

which resolves to `$true`.